# Angular 6 ActivatedRouteSnapshot Service Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

want to save data in firebase using the Id of my detail-component (pah: '/patient/:id'

To save data, I wrote this in data-service  :

```
 createNewTumeur(newTumeur: Tumeur) 
 {
 const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
 console.log(id);
 this.tumeurs.push(newTumeur);
 firebase.database().ref('/patients/'+id).child("tumeur").update(this.tumeurs);
 this.tumeurSubject.next(this.tumeurs);
```

But i can't have the value of id... what is wrong please ?

Comment: Why can't you save? Does the browser console show any errors? Please, give some more details.

Comment: The console says that id is undefined

Comment: if i write this i can save in the good place firebase.database().ref('/patients/'0).child("tumeur").update(this.tumeurs);

Comment: So I guess your `console.log(id);` is displaying undefined. Do your URL contains the id property? How does your route for this component look like?

Comment: Yes my URL contains the id property my route for this component is :   { path: 'patients/:id', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], component: SinglePatientComponent },

Comment: @Alisson No ideas ?

Comment: Are you using activatedRoute or router as your this.route variable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
// my.component.ts

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MyDataService } from './my-data.service';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: MyDataService)

createNewTumeur(newTumeur: Tumeur) {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  console.log(id);
  this.dataService.createNewTumeur(id)
  // And then add the logic into your dataService
}
```

Note: you can only get router parameters in components and not in services.

This is due to services being singletons that belong to a root injector.
You can either send the route parameter over to your service or provide your service in your component (however this will create another instance of the service, i personally don't recommend this).

```js
Component({
  ...
  providers: [MyDataService]
})
export class MyComponent { ... }
```

Comment: have you an example ?

Comment: Here you go, if you have any further questions feel free to ask: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-u9xykv

Comment: thank you very much, i have some difficulty soo i go to work... ^^

Comment: @boost block https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845281/firebase-angular-multiform-in-same-objet-activedroute